# Why can I only refer to the last element in a TextView array I'm passing to onClickListener

Tags: java, android, arrays, loops, view

I have dynamically created a group of 30 TextViews and am trying to change their background colors when I click on them. They are displayed as a list of vertical pairs with spaces in between each pair. When I click the top TextView, I want it to turn green and the one immediately below it to turn red, and vice versa for the bottom one.

The problem I am having right now is that when I click a bottom TextView, it only sets the very last TextView, i.e. myTextViews[n-1]. And when I click on a top TextView, I get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

I would use setTag, getTag, but I'm not sure I can call a previous tag.

```java
public class MainActivity extends OtherActivity {
int i = null;

    final TextView[] myTextViews = new TextView[names.size()]; // create an empty array;

        for (i = 0; i < names.size(); i++) {
            // create a new TextView
            final TextView rowTextView = new TextView(this);

            // save a reference to the TextView for later
            myTextViews[i] = rowTextView;

            // set some properties of rowTextView
            rowTextView.setText(names.get(i));

            // Create onClickListeners for each choice
            if ((i+1)%3 != 0) {
                if (i%3 == 0) {
                    // Sets onClick rules for top choice
                    rowTextView.setOnClickListener(new  View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            rowTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                            myTextViews[i+1].setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                        }
                    });
                } else if ((i-1)%3 == 0) {
                     // Sets onClick rules for bottom choice
                     rowTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                             rowTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                             myTextViews[i-1].setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                        }
                     });
                }
            }
       }
}
```

Comment: That code doesn't compile. You can't do `myTextViews[i+1].setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);` in `onClick()` because `i` is not `final`. You can't get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` if the code doesn't compile. Can you clarify?

Comment: As a temporary solution, and I know this is bad practice, I declared i as a global. Would this force it in as a final and just use its last value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a bit confused about your question as I indicate in my comment. You can't use an index in the `onClick` method without that variable being `final`, and you can't make the variable `final` because then it's the same for all the views. The solution is something like this (It's not been tested. There may be a missing bracket or a typo).

```
TextView[] myTextViews = new TextView[names.size()];
for (int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++) {
     myTextViews[i] = new TextView(this);
     myTextViews[i].setText(names.get(i));
}
for (int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++) {
    final TextView thisOne = myTextViews[i];
    if (i%3 == 0) {
        final TextView nextOne = myTextViews[i+1];
        thisOne.setOnClickListener(new View.onClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                thisOne.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                nextOne.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
            }
        });
    } else if ((i-1)%3 == 0) {
        final TextView previousOne = myTextViews[i-1];
        thisOne.setOnClickListener(new View.onClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                thisOne.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                previousOne.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            }
        });
    }
}
```